# Custom arrow key navigation not working properly (one part works)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrow-keys

I have a large HTML table with dynamically added rows.

The table has a standard structure (incl. thead, tbody and tfoot).

Within this table there are **editable TDs** (which have the `class "editable"` and contain a `contenteditable div`) and non-editable TDs (which dont't have the class "editable" and do not contain a div).

I am trying to **create a custom arrow key navigation that allows me to jump from one editable TD to next or previous one** (like in an Excel table).

To test this I used the below example but this only works partially, i.e. the alerts are shown correctly but I am not able to do anything with the corresponding div (e.g. change its background or add a text etc.).

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

**My jQuery (in doc ready):**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 37: // left arrow
            alert('test left');
            $(this).closest('td').prevUntil('td.editable').find('div').text('test');
            break;
        case 39: // right arrow
            alert('test right');
            $(this).closest('td').nextUntil('td.editable').find('div').text('test');
            break;
        default: // exit for other keys
            return;
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
});
```

**My HTML (example row):**

```
<tr>
    // ...
    <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td> <!-- editable -->
    <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td> <!-- editable -->
    <td></td> <!-- non-editable -->
    <td></td> <!-- non-editable -->
    <td class="editable"><div contenteditable="true"></div></td> <!-- editable -->
    // ...
</tr>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in your code refers do `document` not single element

if you use `$(e.target)` you can get single element

Also you should use [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function instead of [`nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

```
$(e.target).closest('td').nextAll('td.editable:first').find('div').text('test');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works if all TDs are editable but not if there are non-editable ones in between + it doesn't seem to work across TRs, i.e. to jump from the last editable TD in a row to the first one in the next row. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Thanks - let my check. :)

Comment: Now this works within a row but still not when you are at the end of the row and need to jump to the next row etc.

Comment: If you want to jump between rows it can be easier to implement up/down button. If you want to move there by right key you must conditionally check if it is last item in row and then select first item in next row

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try to implement the conditional check as I think it's easier for the user if they don't have to switch arrow keys if they use them. Thanks again !